# Python command line options fail on one account, but not on another

Tags: python, windows, windows-server-2008

I am running on Windows Server 2008.  We use Python extensively on several servers, and for the most part it works well.  However, on at least one server, arguments don't get passed to my python scripts when I run from a command line.  If I log on as a different user, the script works as expected.  I can also run the script in the Eclipse IDE with arguments with no problems.

I will do something like this:

```
myscript.py -h
```

or

```
\Python2.6\python.exe myscript.py -h
```

Rather than display the help, it runs with the default arguments.

If I recall correctly (this has been a problem for a while, so my memory is fuzzy), this account used to run these scripts without a problem.

Comment: Please compare the `PATH` between the two accounts and include both `PATH` settings in your question.

Comment: "I can also run the script in the Eclipse IDE".  This means very, very little.  It isn't a useful diagnostic technique.  What runs in the IDE doesn't matter at all, since you should not be using the IDE for production operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you start a Python script, e.g.:

```
import sys
for a in sys.argv:
  print a
```

with plain

```
showargs.py a b c
```

the effective call is controlled by registry settings witch can be checked with **ftype**

```
ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python25\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

The %* is crucial for passing the arguments to the script. If the %* is missing,

```
ftype Python.File="C:\Python25\python.exe" "%1"
Python.File="C:\Python25\python.exe" "%1"

showargs.py
<no output>
```

the script does not see any arguments. This ftype setting should not affect explicit calls:

```
python showargs.py a b c
showargs.py
a
b
c
```

but "python" on your system/in your IDE could possibly call the 'real' python.exe in a roundabout way - thereby being affected by the ftype settings too. So use ftype for a quick check and/or look at the specification for the "run python script" in your IDE.